# Pagination and Google Books API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, google-books

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project, which uses Google Books API. I managed to implement a pagination with [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate), but I have a small problem. Google always returns different value of totalItems, which is quite confusing, because I am using it to evaluate the total number of pages.

After researching I have found that [this is not a bug](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/books-api/Y_uEJhohJCc).

So my question is maybe are there other ways to implement pagination or to evaluate total number of pages?

Comment: You could hard code totalItems to a large number.

Comment: Thanks, I considered that decision but it seems a bit sloppy.